# Showing NULL values after adding column in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

i am  using hive-version 1.2.1. i m newbie to hive.
i have added a column to TABLE_2 and shows NULL value. i want to put DATE part from timestamp column to newly created column. i tried with below query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_2 ADD COLUMNS(DATE_COL string);
INSERT INTO table_2 (DATE_COL) AS SELECT SUBSTRING(TIMESTAMP_COL,-19,10) FROM table_1 ;
```

this is working bt still it shows NULL values in newly created DATE_COL.
i want just date in DATE_COL.

table_1 has 13 columns, table_2 has 14 columns (13 + DATE_COL).

TIMESTAMP_COL :- STRING.

DATE_COL - STRING.

please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you using substring(string|binary A, int start, int len) function properly? What makes you to use start index -19. Can you share sample records in your TIMESTAMP column in  table_1?

Comment: @SachinGaikwad i think sustring() starts to count from last value. 19 is total length. so if i say -19 it means it will start from first. thats what how i m doing. if u knw actual technical reason behind this then please share.

Comment: i would suggest to first run this query with select clause with same function and check if the values are true as per your need then go for update or insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UPDATE command :
Syntax:

UPDATE tablename SET column = value [, column = value ...] [WHERE expression]

Hive version 0.14.0: INSERT...VALUES, UPDATE, and DELETE are now available with full ACID support.

Comment: thanks you. i'v checked on net regarding this transactional properties of hive. i hv gone through tutorial also, added hive-site.xml file with valid parameters setting. even though its not working.

Comment: If you are using hive version above  .14 then update work for your query.

Comment: i hv solved the problem it seems.   created external table T_1 with partitioned by(date_col). after that, insert into T_1 partition(date_col) select substring(timestamp_col,-19,10) from table_1;  is it okay to do like this??  pls suggest..!!